# Trigger Email if from google forms values

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the script i am using with my google form/spreadsheet.  The problem is that it will not read the (pick list) values, only text or multiple choice.  How do identify the list values

```
function myNotification(e) {
  if( e.values[10] == "FAIL" ) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("email@jci.com","Process Confirmation Audit Failure","Please Review And Post Follow-Up Actions"); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your form this is hard to guess...

Try using the [Logger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger?hl=en) to see what data is returned in your event e. for example `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))`  or `Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(e))` and build your condition based on the result you want.

EDIT following your comment : the Logger is viewable from the script editor, in the view menu

[image]

Comment: I am using simple google form with ask user to choose either PASS or FAIL from list

Comment: not sure how to run the logger, please more details, thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for the help, it was my error, that took me 2 days to figure out...I had put spaces in from of my list values to make my box bigger on the form... thanks for the help

Comment: another question, how can i obtain the edit url from that form and place it into the email.. thanks in advance

Comment: Please avoid asking another question in comments, start a new thread instead if you don't find an answer by searching this site.